# CGPointZero is nil

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cgpoint

I have a`UIScrollView` which needs to be offset when the view is appearing. The following code used to work, but now `CGPointZero` is returning `nil` and therefore the `UIScrollView` is not being offset.

```
[self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointZero];
```

Any ideas why `CGPointZero` might be returning `nil`? Appreciated.

[image]

Comment: `CGPoint` is a struct. Are you saying `CGPointZero == NULL`? Also, why would you expect the scrollview to be offset, if you trying to make the offset (0,0)?

Comment: `CGPointZero` is not a function, it's a constant definition of a structure that contains a (0,0) point. This might look similar to nil in a debugger, and it should tell the scrollview to be at its default location. But it sounds like you are seeing changed behavior? My guess is that `self.scrollView` might be `nil` so this line isn't doing anything.

Comment: @BenZotto you're definitely right about `self.scrollView` being `nil`, so the problem must be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a figment of your misuse of LLDB. You cannot `po` CGPointZero; it isn't an object (`po` stands for "print object"). I don't know what's up with your `setContentOffset:` code but it has nothing whatever to do with what you're doing in the debugger.

Comment: You're definitely right about `po`. As for `setContentOffset`, that's a built in setter for the `UIScrollView` object, so the problem isn't there. @BenZotto is definitely onto something in that `self.scrollView` is `nil` when this code runs. So the problem likely has to do with that.

Comment: @Max Maybe it is and maybe it isn't, but I believe I've answered the question you actually asked, which was: "Any ideas why CGPointZero might be returning nil?"

Comment: You sure did. Maybe this question will be useful to some other dolt out there like myself :) Thanks.